# alert error in dynamic form angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm trying to show an alert if the field is empty. I made this work for a static form, but when i try this case(dynamic) it's not working. Inputs are getting the name values correctly `(1,2,3)`, but `ng-show` does not understand the value that i'm trying to set.

```
<form name="form" class="css-form">
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="p in params">
    <div>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-ng-model="p.value" ng-required="true" name="{{$index}}">
        <alert type="danger" ng-show="form.$index.$valid">
             <strong>Campo obligatorio.</strong>
             <span></span>
        </alert>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: please go to the following link for a working fiddle. You have not used ng-form. http://jsfiddle.net/chandings/9y6zh14z/1/

Comment: @chandings thanks for the link man, i see that you are using angular1.3.1 and I'm using 1.2.16, so that was the problem. Thanks again.:)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
form[$index].$valid
```